# Fallo sintaxis laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo un error, realmente no se como escribir la funcionalidad para que esta pueda implementar la logica de un if, entiendo que el if finaliza la funcionalidad del enloqued, pero quiero saber como implementar un if en ese sector.

```
 public function terminalEventoListar(Request $request)
    {
     
        $grupo_filtro = $request->post('filtro_grupo');
        $dato_filtro = explode(',', $request->post('filtro_datos'));
        $user = Auth::user();
        $perteneceAGrupo = $user->pertenece_a_grupo();

    /* if($grupo_filtro){
            $filtro = $grupo_filtro;
        } else {
            $filtro = $dato_filtro;
        } */


        if ($perteneceAGrupo) {
            if ($perteneceAGrupo[0]) {
                $datos = TerminalEvento::select(DB::raw('evento.nombre, count(terminal_evento.evento_id) as cantTerminal'), 'terminal_evento.*')
                    ->join('evento', 'terminal_evento.evento_id', '=', 'evento.id')
                    ->join('terminal', 'terminal_evento.terminal_id', '=', 'terminal.id')
                    ->join('subgrupo_terminal', 'subgrupo_terminal.terminal_id', '=', 'terminal.id')
                    ->join('subgrupo', 'subgrupo.id', '=', 'subgrupo_terminal.subgrupo_id')
                    ->groupBy('terminal_evento.evento_id');
                    if($grupo_filtro){
                        ->where('subgrupo.nombre', 'LIKE',  "$grupo_filtro");
                    } else {
                        ->whereIn('terminal.serial', $dato_filtro);
                    }
                    ->get();
            } else {
                $terminalesUsuario = $user->terminals()->get();
                $idsTerminales = [];
                foreach ($terminalesUsuario as $item) {
                    array_push($idsTerminales, $item->id);
                }

                $datos = TerminalEvento::select(DB::raw('evento.nombre, count(terminal_evento.evento_id) as cantTerminal'), 'terminal_evento.*')
                    ->join('evento', 'terminal_evento.evento_id', '=', "evento.id")
                    ->join('terminal', 'terminal_evento.terminal_id', '=', 'terminal.id')
                    ->groupBy('terminal_evento.evento_id')
                    ->whereIn('terminal_evento.terminal_id', $idsTerminales)
                    ->whereIn('terminal.serial', $dato_filtro)
                    ->get();
            } 
        }

        return $datos;
    }
```

**Mi error esta en el if dentro de la consulta a la BD** aqui dejo una imagen para que mas o menos tengan idea donde se ubica el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué dice el mensaje de error? o ¿cuál es exactamente la duda?

Comment: mi duda es el sintaxis, como escribo un if dentro de una sentencia de enloqued mysql

Comment: Al hacer esto `?->where(...)` obviamente obtendrás un error porque prácticamente está en el aire. Debes especificar de dónde `$datos->where(...)`.

Comment: Si el error era ese, pero igualmente generaba otro error, la solucion final era $datos = $datos->where(...)

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis que esta intentando ejecutar dentro del if() no es valida.

Puedes probar lo siguiente, dentro del if y antes del metodo where puedes agregar la variable de la consulta anterior de tal forma que te quede algo como esto:

```
if($grupo_filtro){
    $datos->where('subgrupo.nombre', 'LIKE',  $grupo_filtro);
} else {
    $datos->whereIn('terminal.serial', $dato_filtro);
}
```

No tengo claro si su consulta es correcta, pero eso evitara el error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

yo estoy trabajando un poco con laravel y hasta donde tengo entendido no se pueden agregar condiciones de ese tipo (if,else,...) cuando estas construyendo una consulta con eloquent, query bluider, etc.

```
Ahi tienes 2 opciones
1: (Que no es muy limpia que se diga) pero es duplicando la consulta en 2 y segun el if ejecutas tu consulta
 Ej: 
if(variable==1)
{
$datos=modelo::join()......
->where('subgrupo','like',$variable)
->get();
}
else
{
$datos=modelo::join()......
->where('terminal','like',$variable)
->get();
}


2: la segunda solucion es hacer uso de los queryscope, son de muy utilidad para ese caso en concreto, ya que no tendras que tener duplicada tu consulta.

te dejo un ejemplo segun a documentación

//esto lo creas en tu modelo, parecido a las relaciones
      public function scopeOfType($query, $type)
    {
        return $query->where('type', $type);
    }

//esto es en tu controlador
$users = User::ofType('admin')->get();
```

Comment: a mi me da error el IDEal intentar hacer eso, y creo que ya detecte el error de sintaxis, tienes un " ; " al final del group by , por lo que no toma en cuenta todo lo demas

Comment: jaja perdón no me percaté

Answer (score 0):

Hola amihos lo que soluciona esto ya lo averigue es de esta manera

```
if($grupo_filtro){
    $datos = $datos->where('subgrupo.nombre', 'LIKE',  $grupo_filtro);
} else {
    $datos = $datos->whereIn('terminal.serial', $dato_filtro);
}
```